# Target closest element inside parent li

Tags: jquery

I try to toggle a **div** inside a **li** but its not working for me

```
$('#open_p_table').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('li').find('.players').toggle();
});
```

This is the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/oexf0624/)

What i am doing wrong?

Comment: Thank you! Actually a comment would be enough!!! So many answers, well, I must take the first one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both span elements share this ID: `open_p_table`.

[IDs must be unique](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2). Use classes instead:

```js
$('.open_p_table').on('click', function () {
    $(this).closest('li').find('.players').toggle();
});
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="item">   <span class="open_p_table">Players</span>
        <div class="players">description</div>
    </li>
    <li class="item">   <span class="open_p_table">Players</span>
        <div class="players">description</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/oexf0624/5/)

Answer (score 1):

Id should be uique..! change the `open_p_table` as a class and do,

```js
$('.open_p_table').on('click', function () {
    $(this).closest('li').find('.players').toggle();
});
```

```css
.open_p_table{ cursor:pointer; }
.open_p_table + .players {  display:none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li class="item"><span class="open_p_table">Players</span>
    <div class="players">description</div>
  </li>
  <li class="item"><span class="open_p_table">Players</span>
    <div class="players">description</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of taking duplicate id **open_p_table** take class as shown :

HTML :

```
<ul>
    <li class="item">

            <span class="open_p_table">Players</span>
            <div class="players">
                description
            </div>
        </li>

    <li class="item">

            <span class="open_p_table">Players</span>
            <div class="players">
                description
            </div>
        </li>
</ul>
```

Jquery:

```
$('.open_p_table').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('li').find('.players').toggle();
});
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/oexf0624/3/)

Answer (score 1):

First Id's must be unique, so change it to class like:

```
$('.open_p_table').on('click', function() {
        $(this).closest('li').find('.players').toggle();
    });
```

And you HTML:

```
<li class="item">
            <span class="open_p_table">Players</span>
            <div class="players">
                description
            </div>
        </li>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/oexf0624/2/)

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/oexf0624/1/

You were re-using an `id` (which must be unique) - I changed it to a `class` and now it works :)

```
$('.open_p_table').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('li').find('.players').toggle();
});
```

---

```
<span class="open_p_table">Players</span>
<div class="players">
    description
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using ID for selecter. However, if there are multiple same IDs in a DOM, this will select only the first element with that ID. You will need to use the class.

```
$('.open_p_table').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('li').find('.players').toggle();
});
```

and your HTML will be

```
<ul>
    <li class="item">

            <span class="open_p_table">Players</span>
            <div class="players">
                description
            </div>
        </li>

    <li class="item">

            <span class="open_p_table">Players</span>
            <div class="players">
                description
            </div>
        </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

use a class selector

```
$('.open_p_table').on('click', function() {
        $(this).closest('li').find('.players').toggle();
    });
```

ID's are normally suppose to be unique